# Access from xml to other xml?

Tags: android, xml

How to access from xml file to values in other xml. I need to access to xml which was created by SharedPreferences and is in folder shared_prefs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an "inner" join with XSLT

Comment: Do you have any example? ..i don't find any usefull

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xmlandnetfx/thread/b1e4e9f2-1156-4191-81e7-c63fbecf1bc6 look at this one

Comment: Isn't it any easy solution like this but syntactically correct? 

    <EditTextPreference
        .
        .
        .
     android:defaultValue="@data/data/com.myapp/shared_prefs/toastTime"
        .
        .
        .
    </PreferenceCategory>

Works when you read from strings under values(folder) android:defaultValue="@strings/toeastTime"